# Change the ids in my SQL Server table so they would be a sequence

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with a unique auto-incremental primary key. Some entries have been deleted from the table, so there are gaps in the ids, it is not a sequence.

I need a query that will make it a sequence. the table is not connected with any other table, so I can temporarily remove the pk and auto-increment from the id column (until the ids will be a sequence).

1. I use SQL server
2. If possible, I want to run the query starting from specific id

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update identity column values, nor you can remove the identity from the column, update the values and set it back. You must create a new table with the same schema, copy the data from the old table, but for ID generate a new value, drop the old table and rename the new one to keep the same name.

```
use [tempdb]
go

if OBJECT_ID('TestTable') is not null
    drop table TestTable
go

create table TestTable (
    ID int not null primary key clustered identity(1,1)
    , Name varchar(50)
)

insert into TestTable(Name) values
    ('Row #1'),('Row #2'),('Row #3'),
    ('Row #4'),('Row #5'),('Row #6'),
    ('Row #7'),('Row #8'),('Row #9')

delete from TestTable where ID in (3, 4, 8) -- Make some gaps

create table TestTable_NEW (
    ID int not null primary key clustered identity(1,1)
    , Name varchar(50)
)

insert into TestTable_NEW(Name)
select Name
from TestTable
order by ID -- Preserve the rows order

drop table TestTable

exec sp_rename N'TestTable_NEW', N'TestTable'
```

However, I will not recommend doing this at all. Identity values are supposed to be immutable. They should **never** change. If you have problems with gaps, then do not allow deletion of existing records. Also, identity **do not guarantee** that there will be no gaps in the sequence. Only that the values will be unique and increasing. So you should definitely reconsider your database and/or application design, because it is flawed.

Comment: I can remove the pk and the identity increment from the id, I did it. if this is the case can I do it with one query without creating a new table?

Comment: As I said, you can't remove the identity from the column. It will recreate the table anyway.